# Custom Angular JS directive for validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm new to JavaScript and Angular JS. 
I have to write a custom directive to validate the content of an input field passed in an .aspx page; more precisely I have to check if an username with the value passed in the input already exists. In my directve I have to call a service that checks for duplicates in the db and afterwards depending on the result I have to perform a success callback/error callback and to return an object containing info about the validation check and a message to diplay. In particular I'm stuck on this last part regarding callbacks and returning an object with info (in my version I cannot use $.defer).

Unfortunaltely, I cannot take advantage of the already existing custom validation for forms provided by Angular (that is $asynchrounous validators and $q.defer) as I have to use an older version of Angular 1.2.26.
Could you provide me some hints/examples on how to achieve it? I'm trying hard but I still find custom directives a bit difficult and I cannot find examples for custom validation (except for those based on Angular 1.3 $asynch validators).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use $http service in your directive's link or controller function and do operations with response data. What is the problem exactly can you be more clear?

Comment: Yes I've used $http service to call my service for validation (and everything is fine there). What I don't understand is afterwards my service call, how to implement the success/error callbacks to provide a mechanism similar to $.when $.resolve $.reject so as to mimic $q.defer. Thank you

Comment: `    function login(username, password) {
      return $http.post(API_URL = '/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }).then(function success(response) {
        AuthTokenFactory.setToken(response.data.token);
        return response;
      });
    }` Here is a code snippet from companies code base.

Comment: promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});

Comment: thank you very much! So, if I understood right the ".then" part will mimic the $q.defer, right? Then, to display the result object fields' data, that is: validity status and error message I have to define a one way binding in the .aspx right? thanks

Comment: I guess so. $http returns a promise object and you can use ".then()" on that object to get data and do operations with that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own directive for this: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjaVFsAK7B7PLG44dkBE?p=preview)

```
app.directive('asyncNameCheck', function($http){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel){
      elm.bind('input', function(){
        ngModel.$setValidity('asyncValid', false);
        $http.get('http://graph.facebook.com/facebook')
          .success(function(data){
            ngModel.$setValidity('asyncValid', true);
          });
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and in the html

```
<form name="myform">
  <input name="testfield" async-name-check required ng-model="test"/>
  <p ng-show="myform.testfield.$error.asyncValid">This field is invalid</p>
</form>
```

Just note that this directive is not a reusable one but works for your requirements.  Do not do this in the controller, I've spent a lot of time with angular validation and if you're controlling validation in the controller, it will cause you alot of issues later on.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much for the example. I don't know if $setValidity is available in my Amgular version but I will check.

Comment: when I was working with 1.0.8 I initially had the same problem.  I tried to control validity with the controller and it caused a lot of issues.  However, when I discovered $setValidity in 1.0.8, life was awesome.  Note this can only be done in a directive.